# Script to get maximum password age's remaining days in Win10

Tags: windows-10, script, group-policy

How do make a script to get maximum password age's remaining days in group policy in Win10?
I need this to monitor and inform the users when they are going to change their password.

Suppose you have:

Date the Group Policy last edited: 1 day ago

Maximum password age: 3 days

How do get two days remaining?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I could only get the password's last change date and substract with the maximum password age set in the gpo by written data (not from the PC itself), and I have no any idea where to start. I'm not sure I understand how `maximum password age` work, like does the duration decreases age of `maximum password age` start from when I set the `maximum password age` or from when I last change the `password` itself?

Comment: `net user USERNAME /domain | find "password expires"`. For local account do not specify `/domain` option.

Comment: Thanks @Akina, but my systems says `never` and I have only administrator account.

Comment: If system reports *Password expires: never*, then max. password age is not set.

Comment: omg but im using local security policy to set the max password age https://gyazo.com/741b55966cb8af09b74d3157780a1e2c?